# Passing Data between VCs: prepareForSegue vs Singleton

Tags: swift, singleton, segue, viewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

Say I am switching Views via a segue and I know that most of the data I want to pass to a new VC will get passed to multiple other VCs in later segues. I am pretty new to swift/cocoa development, but as far as I am concerned, the standard way of passing this data would be via the prepareForSegue function. This seems to be pretty repetitive though, as I am passing the same data over and over again. Wouldn't it be easier to have some kind of singleton class to store that data and manipulate it with the current VC? I'm pretty sure Apple has a better solution for this though.

Is it ok to use singletons for this kind of scenario or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singletons can be accessed directly from anywhere in the app. Singletons introduce coupling in your code and make your objects hard to test.

There are two ways to pass data forward.

1. Passing data when a segue is performed
2. Passing data when a transition is performed through code

Both could be boring but I think there is no way except them.